# Set the timestamp on a Linux file in C#

Tags: c#, linux, timestamp

does anyone know how to set the time-stamp of a Linux (text) file to an arbitrary value, not necessarily the current time, using C#?

For example, could I run code to change the timestamp of `filepath/foobar` to `Thu 04 Oct 1995 09:15:00 AM CDT`?

Preferably, this would work for both the accessed and modified stamps.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question you would want to use File.SetLastWriteTime().  More information on it can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setlastwritetime.aspx

Comment: That does the trick. Is there a similar way to modify the last read time? `File.SetLastReadTime` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: You should be able to set it with LastAccessTime() http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime.aspx